# cmake: forcing build type for a specific library fails

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a c++ project made of several executables and libraries. I use cmake for the compilation. Also in debug mode, I add “_d” as postfix for the libraries (i.e.: libfoo_d.so).

Now, one of those libraries (say lib1) is so slow in debug mode that I want to always build it in release mode. So, in the CMakeLists.txt of lib1 I am forcing the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Release:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
```

This library has dependencies (say lib2). Of course, lib2 should still be compiled in debug mode and its name should be liblib2_d.so (I only want lib1 to be in release mode).

Unfortunately, when building (in debug mode), I get the following error message:

`[build] make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'binaries/lib/liblib2.so', needed by 'binaries/lib/liblib1_d.so'.  Stop.`

Here is the CMakeLists.txt file for lib1:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)

if (CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)
   project (lib1)
endif()

if (NOT TARGET lib2)
   add_subdirectory(../lib2 lib2)
endif()

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/binaries/lib/)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

include_directories(include)
include_directories(../lib2/include lib2)

add_library(lib1 SHARED src/src1.cpp include/lib1.h)

target_link_libraries(lib1 lib2)
```

I am using cmake version 3.18.4.

I have also uploaded [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/de6d9ad2898c79436ab41c422c74ba6e20211022124833/2113e5), a sample that shows the issue. Just unzip the content and run:

`mkdir build && cd build && cmake --configure ../app -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug && cmake --build .`

I don't know how to solve this. Please can you help me?